# AppCenter Device Testing - Test Case Method Failure

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-app-center, xcuitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

What causes the error `Test Case Method Failure`?  It is all that shows when running a test on some devices in the AppCenter device Test Cloud.  When I download the logs for each failed test they are empty so I have no clue why the test is failing.  For some reason this is appearing on devices below ios 13.

My app:
Cordova hybrid
targeting 11.0 
built with SDK 13.3
Test framework: XCUITest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had no logs because I was testing a Release build.  After changing to a debug build, now I have logs.